# How to remove the XML namespace from a specific child node

Tags: delphi, xml-namespaces, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am writing a Delphi (10.4) program to export a database to XML. The purpose is to open the `.xml` file directly into Excel. I am using a working `.xml` as the basis for what needs to be exported.

When I try to open the exported file, I get an error:

> This file cannot be opened because of errors.

I have already narrowed it down to one line in the `.xml`:

```xml
<Styles xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
```

In the original, this is simply as follows:

```xml
<Styles>
```

This is a child node of the root. The child nodes before this have the same `xmlns` in the original and exported files.

Below is the code I am using.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  XML : IXMLDOCUMENT;
  RootNode, CurNode, ChildNode, ChildNode2, ChildNode3 : IXMLNODE;
  ns, nso, nsx, nsss, nshtml : String;
begin
  XML := NewXMLDocument;
  XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent]; // looks better in Editor ;)
  ns := 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet';
  nso := 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office';
  nsx:= 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel';
  nsss := 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet';
  nshtml := 'http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40';

  RootNode := XML.AddChild('Workbook');
    RootNode.DeclareNamespace('', ns);
    RootNode.DeclareNamespace('o', nso);
    RootNode.DeclareNamespace('x', nsx);
    RootNode.DeclareNamespace('ss', nsss);
    RootNode.DeclareNamespace('html', nshtml);

    CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('DocumentProperties');/////////////////////////DocumentProperties
    CurNode.DeclareNamespace('', nso);
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('Author', nso);
        ChildNode.Text := 'File Author';
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('LastAuthor', nso);
        ChildNode.Text := 'File Editor';
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('Created', nso);
        ChildNode.Text := DateToStr(Now);
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('LastSaved', nso);
        ChildNode.Text := DateToStr(Now);
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('Version', nso);
        ChildNode.Text := '16.00';

    CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('OfficeDocumentSettings');/////////////////////OfficeDocumentSettings
    CurNode.DeclareNamespace('', nso);
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('AllowPNG', nso);

     CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('ExcelWorkbook');/////////////////////////////ExcelWorkbook
     CurNode.DeclareNamespace('', nso);
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('WindowHeight', nso);
        ChildNode.Text := '8976';
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('WindowWidth', nso);
        ChildNode.Text := '23040';
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('WindowTopX', nso);
        ChildNode.Text := '32767';
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('WindowTopY', nso);
        ChildNode.Text := '32767';
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('ProtectStructure', nso);
        ChildNode.Text := 'False';
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('ProtectWindows', nso);
        ChildNode.Text := 'False';


    CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('Styles');/////////////////////////////////////Styles
      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('Style', nso);
        ChildNode.Attributes['ss:ID'] := 'Default';
        ChildNode.Attributes['ss:Name'] := 'Normal';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Alignment', nso);
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Vertical'] := 'Bottom';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Borders', nso);
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Font', nso);
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:FontName'] := 'Calibri';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['x:Family'] := 'Swiss';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Size'] := '11';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Color'] := '#000000';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Interior', nso);
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('NumberFormat', nso);
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Protection', nso);

       ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('Style', nso);
        ChildNode.Attributes['ss:ID'] := 's64';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Alignment', nso);
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Vertical'] := 'Center';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:WrapText'] := '1';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Borders', nso);
            ChildNode3 := ChildNode2.AddChild('Border', nso);
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:Position'] := 'Right';
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:LineStyle'] := 'Continuous';
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:Weight'] := '1';
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:Color'] := '#FFFFFF';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Font', nso);
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:FontName'] := 'Calibri';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['x:Family'] := 'Swiss';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Size'] := '11';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Color'] := '#FFFFFF';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Interior', nso);
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Color'] := '#44546A';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Pattern'] := 'Solid';

        ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('Style', nso);
        ChildNode.Attributes['ss:ID'] := 's65';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Alignment', nso);
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Vertical'] := 'Center';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:WrapText'] := '1';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Borders', nso);
            ChildNode3 := ChildNode2.AddChild('Border', nso);
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:Position'] := 'Left';
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:LineStyle'] := 'Continuous';
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:Weight'] := '1';
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:Color'] := '#FFFFFF';
            ChildNode3 := ChildNode2.AddChild('Border', nso);
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:Position'] := 'Right';
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:LineStyle'] := 'Continuous';
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:Weight'] := '1';
              ChildNode3.Attributes['ss:Color'] := '#FFFFFF';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Font', nso);
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:FontName'] := 'Calibri';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['x:Family'] := 'Swiss';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Size'] := '11';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Color'] := '#FFFFFF';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Interior', nso);
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Color'] := '#44546A';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Pattern'] := 'Solid';

      ChildNode := CurNode.AddChild('Style', nso);
        ChildNode.Attributes['ss:ID'] := 's66';
          ChildNode2 := ChildNode.AddChild('Alignment', nso);
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:Vertical'] := 'Bottom';
            ChildNode2.Attributes['ss:WrapText'] := '1';

  XMl.SaveToFile('export.xml');
end;
```

I have folded screenshots of both the original and exported XML files to show the child nodes.

Original:
[image]

Exported:
[image]

I tried adding and removing namespaces, but I cannot get `<Styles>` to be without any `xmlns` - the best I got was `<Styles xmlns="">` and that gives me the same error.

Just a note: The `Worksheet` child node is not in the program, as I still need to get to that part. I copied the data from the original XML file for the purpose of testing.

Comment: Try changing `XML.AddChild('Workbook')` to `XML.AddChild('Workbook', ns)`, and change `CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('DocumentProperties'); CurNode.DeclareNamespace('', nso);` to `CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('DocumentProperties', nso);` and similarly for `RootNode.AddChild('OfficeDocumentSettings')`, `RootNode.AddChild('ExcelWorkbook')`, `RootNode.AddChild('Styles')`, etc. *Every* node should have a namespace specified when it is being *created*, don't *declare* its namespace *after* the node is created (unless it is declaring *new* namespaces for its child nodes to use, as the root node does)

Comment: All of those extra `xmlns` attributes on the child nodes are redundant, since they are already declared in the root node.  The child nodes *should* be using the registered prefixes instead, eg: `<o:DocumentProperties>`, `<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>`, `<x:ExcelWorkbook>`, `<x:WorksheetOptions>`, etc

Comment: Thank you, those changes regarding the namespace did the trick. I did what you said and ```delphi CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('Styles'); ``` exported ```xml <styles> ``` that was necessary. The child nodes now had the xmlns, but removing the nso part from their ```AddChild ``` fixed that.